# End Date greater than Start Date Validation

Tags: javascript, html

I am using this code for the validation, it works fine when using the default datepicker in html but when typing the date manually, it's not properly working. For example, when I type a start date then  proceed to the endate, the year in the end date automatically reads only the first number of "2019" so you can't finish typing properly since it alerts and can't compare properly.

```
<input type="date" id="StartDate" />
<input type="date" id="EndDate" />
<script>
console.clear();
 var startDate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
 var endDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;

function compareDates() {
  if ((Date.parse(endDate) <= Date.parse(startDate))) {
    alert("End date should be greater than Start date");
    document.getElementById("EndDate").value = "";
   }
 }

startDate.addEventListener('input', compareDates);
endDate.addEventListener('input', compareDates);
</script>
```

Any tips?

Comment: Do you need to do this dynamically? Can't you do the javascript comparison after clicking a submit button?

Comment: You could check first whether the dates are valid, for instance between 1900 and 2500, before you issue an alert.

Comment: javascript date parsing can be a little flakey. ___What format do you enter a date in your locale___ [see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)

Comment: I'm creating a search function in my system so i can't do the submit button.